# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'create_timestamp' cannot be null")

Tags: python, django

This is the full output after execute script this error is present when run script on python I use django 1.10 python 2.7

```
File "/usr/bin/snort-sig-parser.py", line 213, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/snort-sig-parser.py", line 205, in main
    sig_parse(sig_line, 0,options.branch,options.revision)
  File "/usr/bin/snort-sig-parser.py", line 173, in sig_parse
    sig_obj.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 796, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 824, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 908, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 947, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1043, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1054, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 117, in execute
    six.reraise(utils.IntegrityError, utils.IntegrityError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 112, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'create_timestamp' cannot be null")
```

this script not write on mysql database.

This is part of code on models.

```
class SignatureUpdateSet(models.Model):
create_timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
branch = models.CharField(max_length=80)
revision = models.IntegerField()
new_signatures = models.ManyToManyField(Signature,related_name='new_signatures')
updated_signatures = models.ManyToManyField(Signature,related_name='updated_signatures')
deleted_signatures = models.ManyToManyField(Signature,related_name='deleted_signatures')
#blogpost_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
blogpost = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost,null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'content_app_signatureupdateset'
```

Comment: The error cannot be any more obvious,  you are leaving empty for a database field that shouldn't be when you save the data. We couldn't help you without you showing us your model.

Comment: In your `create_timestamp` field, add the attribute `auto_now_add=True`https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add

Comment: this is the full code on models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `auto_now=True` in your `create_timestamp` field if you want to add Time Stamp automatically, else if you want to add anything other than current time stamp, you can add`blank=True`  and add any custom time stamp if you like before saving.

```
create_timestamp = DateTimeField(auto_now=True) # To save current datetime

create_timestamp = DateTimeField(blank=True) # To save any custom date time
```